# Cronjob is not running in Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cron

So I am trying to automate backups to S3 buckets through linux.

The script I am trying to run is

```
TIME=`date +%b-%d-%y`           
FILENAME=backup-$TIME.tar.gz    
SRCDIR=/opt/nexus                     
DESDIR=/usr/local/backup            
tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR 
aws s3 cp /usr/local/backup/backup.tar.gz s3://s3backup
```

The cronjob to run that script is `44 11 * * * ./backup.sh`

However whenever I  try to run the backup script (by updating cronjob) it does not seem to be working at all.

Any ideas why it will not work?

Comment: is the cronjob in the cron owned by your user account, or in /etc/crontab ?

Comment: I set the user at centos which should be correct

Comment: please update the question with what it says in ``/var/log/cron`` when the job is run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a date stamped backup file, but attempting to copy static file name. Try changing the copy command to:

```
aws s3 cp $DESDIR/$FILENAME s3://s3backup
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use relative path names in cron job or script.

```
44 11 * * * ./backup.sh
```

Instead, use full path of the script.

```
44 11 * * * <full_path>/backup.sh
```

In addition, use full path in your script:

```
<full_path>/tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR 
<full_path>aws s3 cp /usr/local/backup/backup.tar.gz s3://s3backup
```

Make sure the cron job is added for the user who has the AWS credentials set up correctly.